# (Cosmos DB) System functions in composite indexes are range filters?

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos DB document says

> Queries with multiple range filters can also be optimized with a
> composite index. However, each individual composite index can only
> optimize a single range filter. Range filters include >, <, <=, >=,
> and !=. The range filter should be defined last in the composite
> index.

What about system functions ?

For example, `CONTAINS`, `ARRAY_CONTAINS`, `BETWEEN`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation does not mention that system functions can benefit from composite index. Then I test this. No matter if I make or not use composite index, I get the same RU/S. It seems that composite index can't work for system functions.

Tested SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.age = 20 and (c.partitionkey between '1' and '5') and contains(c.data,'str') order by c.name desc
```